# How to save the webpage data as pdf using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf

Using window.showmodaldialog(), populating HTML data as popup.

We need the same populated data as PDF using JavaScript (Without using third party tools), how can we do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want a fully client-side solution, I would look into the [jsPDF](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf) library. Apparently it can process HTML now.